# Are IE9 events fully DOM Level 2 Compliant?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, internet-explorer-9

Can anyone tell me if IE9 is fully DOM level 2 compliant? For example, that it now supports `.stopPropagation()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, events in IE 9 are fully DOM 2 compliant and support [`stopPropagation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`preventDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) methods.

Here's a test case that proves it: http://jsfiddle.net/pke26/

Comment: This answer would be much better if it liked to some sort of test case or compatiblility matrix or something...

Comment: @Sean: Yes, I agree. I've added a test case.